Getting err:Connection_Reset on a post request
I'm getting a err:Connection_Reset error when posting a axios request with 1000+ rows.
it works on my test server but not working on the production server
sometimes i get the err:Connection_Reset error on the console

and sometimes i get "This Page can't be displayed"

this is my code where it send to the API.
public function curlPostRequest(Request $request)
    {                   
        $oOutput = Http::withHeaders(['user-username' => \Session::get('username')])->withToken(\Session::get('rrpm_api_acc_token'))->post($this->sApiRoute, $request->all());       
        return response($oOutput, $oOutput->status());
    }

If I'm only posting like 10-20 rows it's successfully saved, already set my PHP config same as the test server but still no luck on the production server.
this.axios.post('./rrpm-api/journalVoucher/saveJvDetails', this.third_page_data, config)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.loading(false);
                        if(response.data.code == 0){
                            let oldthis = this;
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                Swal.fire({
                                    icon: 'success',
                                    text: 'Saved!',
                                    showCancelButton: false,
                                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                                    confirmButtonText: 'ok',
                                }).then((result) => {
                                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                                        let jv_number = response.data.jv_number;
                                        let jv_date = response.data.jv_date;
                                        let jv_status = response.data.jv_status;
                                        
                                        oldthis.directCloseThirdpage('save', jv_number, jv_date, jv_status);
                                    }
                                })
                            }, 100, oldthis);
                        }else{
                            if(response.data.where){
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    Swal.fire({
                                        icon: 'error',
                                        title: 'Message',
                                        text: response.data.where, 
                                    })
                                }, 100);
                            }else{
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    Swal.fire({
                                        icon: 'error',
                                        title: 'Message',
                                        text: response.data.message,
                                    })
                                }, 100);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        if(error.response.data.where){
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                Swal.fire({
                                    icon: 'error',
                                    title: 'Message',
                                    text: error.response.data.where, 
                                })
                            }, 100);
                        }else{
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                Swal.fire({
                                    icon: 'error',
                                    title: error.response.statusText,
                                    html: error.response.statusText,
                                });
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    });


If you just do 1 row of axios post, would it still have the same error? Maybe the cause of error is because you are sending 1000 rows of data?

it works for low number of rows. but in my test server both low and 1000+ number of rows works, and i already copied the php config of my test server to prod server but still no luck .
